# How to send commands to a microcontroller from an HTML page without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just registered on this website because I found it really interesting and detailed, and I already have a question for you!

I'm trying to create an HTML page that can work as a Remote Control for a microcontroller (Raspberry Pi) to play music and control it from distance (from a laptop, phone etc.). I implemented in my page buttons like Play, Pause, Stop etc. etc. but I don't know how to send those "variables" to the microcontroller. I would like to send them as characters so that, for example, when the microcontroller reads "P" it know that it has to play music. Last question is: when I send a value (for example PLAY), how can I be sure that the page will not refresh? Thank you in advance! This is my code for the form:

Comment: Oh sorry, i cannot enter the code...

Comment: does your pi microcontroller have any api? how do remote control it (line/wifi/bluetooth/ir/screwdrive )?